# Editing question and answer displays inline tag editor above question title

Tags: bug, edits, inline-tag-editor

If you have 10k reputation (which gives the ability to [edit tags on the fly](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/06/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/)), and you edit both the question and then an answer, the inline tag editor is shown above the question title. Demonstration:

[image]